# Exact string search using lambda function

Tags: python, pandas

How can one search for exact string using a lambda function? The data frame looks as follows:

```
A  B     
10 Mini 

20 Mini Van

15 Mini

13 Mini Bus
```

Desired results

```
A   B

10  Mini

15  Mini
```

I have tried the following, but all fail:

```
df_temp = df_temp[df_temp['B'].apply(lambda x: 'mini' in x)] and
df_temp = df_temp[df_temp['B'].apply(lambda x: 'mini' in x.str.match())]
```

Thank you

Comment: Try to format the code in your question using ctrl+k. It is currently hard to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check for equality:

```
df_temp = df_temp[df_temp['B'] == 'Mini']
```

This works because `df_temp['B'] == 'Mini'` returns a Boolean series, which is then used to index `df_temp`.

Or you can use [`pd.DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for more intuitive syntax:

```
df_temp = df_temp.query('B == "Mini"')
```

[`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) is just a thinly veiled loop; it should be reserved for when you *need* to explicitly operate on a series one item at a time in a loop. It is inefficient and verbose versus indexing via the above methods.